# Python code example for identifying and reformatting files does not generate output. File names may be a problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io, glob

I would like to use this code (link follows) for combining and reformatting two files.  I'm using Python 3.7.  I have also added a line at the top of the code (just above "`dir =`") to go to go to a particular directory on an external machine:

```
os.chdir("/externalDirectory)
```

https://github.com/pollardtp/asepylot/blob/master/cp2k/xyzcell2gro.py

My problem is that I get no output at all--not even any errors.  My file names may be the problem.  I have very little experience in dealing with the sort of string manipulation used in the example code and have not been able to find any resources online (that I can understand) to make sure the code is consistent with my file names. I would be very grateful for any advice.

Here are short examples of the two files I want to combine.  They are actually much longer than shown here.  I apologize because I can't get the formatting tools here to recognize the headings in (1), below, for each column:

1. Name: ar1o1.ai-1.cell

Step   Time [fs]       Ax [Angstrom]       Ay [Angstrom]       Az [Angstrom]       Bx [Angstrom]       By [Angstrom]       Bz [Angstrom]       Cx [Angstrom]       Cy [Angstrom]       Cz [Angstrom]      Volume [Angstrom^3]

```
       0       0.000       13.6105000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6105000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6105000000          2521.2867393576
       1       0.500       13.6102685896        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6102685896        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6102685896          2521.1581382194
       2       1.000       13.6101388560        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101388560        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101388560          2521.0860435793
       3       1.500       13.6101072636        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101072636        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101072636          2521.0684874332
       4       2.000       13.6101684346        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101684346        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6101684346          2521.1024806622
       5       2.500       13.6103158075        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6103158075        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6103158075          2521.1843781105
       6       3.000       13.6105421149        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6105421149        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6105421149          2521.3101442384
       7       3.500       13.6108396949        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6108396949        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6108396949          2521.4755251397
       8       4.000       13.6112007464        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6112007464        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6112007464          2521.6761902243
       9       4.500       13.6116175884        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6116175884        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6116175884          2521.9078757315
      10       5.000       13.6120829540        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6120829540        0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000       13.6120829540          2522.1665480108
```

2. Name: ar1o1.ai-pos-1.xyz
   Each row in (1) above corresponds to one block like the one shown below:

> ```
>      193
>  i =        0, time =        0.000, E =     -1862.5354785273
>  Ar         2.7122680189       11.0569574242        6.8765696187
>  Ar         1.7122680189        7.0569574242        2.8765696187
>  Ar         9.8778827417        5.5336942397        3.4088988234
>  Ar        10.1738894899       10.9594639697       10.1225475792
>  Ar         1.7122680189       10.5695742424        2.8765696187
>  Ar         0.8778827417       -0.5336942397        0.4088988234
>  Ar         0.1738894899        6.9594639697       -2.1225475792
>  Ar        -8.0921793354        6.4673780979        2.6251511813
>  Ar        -5.1738894899       -0.9594639697       -7.1225475792
>  Ar         4.1738894899       -7.9594639697       12.1225475792
>  Ar        -1.8883177192        2.5779469261        0.5653027312
>  Ar       -12.1788878042      -11.1797317728       -4.1689581282
>  Ar        -1.2437143627       -7.3450060106        8.1546181679
>  Ar       -13.1569987126      -10.8930038241        3.9846746417
>  F        12.8778827417       12.0000000000        9.2088988234
>  F         8.8778827417        9.5336942397        5.4088988234
>  F        10.8778827417        6.5336942397        4.4088988234
>  F        -3.1804249835       -8.0511664361       -0.0634952634
>  F        -2.3180424984       -2.8051166436       -2.0634952634
>  F         0.2825887288        7.5730975228        8.4890272614
>  F        -2.1081443718       -2.7537095541        1.0701130638
>  F        13.1804249835        2.0051166436       10.6349526336
>  F       -10.5034667856      -10.2143171298       10.2319427035
>  F         9.5399907183        6.1139006636        8.1850398107
>  F        -3.6244579979       -2.1357924886       -7.4495906624
>  F        -9.5307587140       -5.9247290040        1.8917478200
>  F       -11.9194078734       -3.0578316157       -4.7429014962
>  F        -2.3180424984       -0.2805116644      -10.6349526336
>   O        -7.6415350292        6.0494971539        8.1919697993
>   H        -6.6418362233        5.9231018862        8.4056822626
>   H        -8.0518670684        6.3158684817        9.0061271154
>   O        26.8252967820       20.4661074967       17.8025744066
>   H        26.4477411207       20.4071029058       16.9121571912
>   H        26.4399648474       21.2950722068       18.1009273227
>   O         9.7969899605       -3.6862465008      -13.5983841774
>   H         9.1770475981       -4.1166444002      -13.0084523440
>   H         9.4355677986       -3.8791356276      -14.4327460918
>   O        10.9460655813       12.7176262648       11.2970131628
>   H        10.0391090538       12.9077389574       11.3800060439
>   H        11.2756367722       13.0379976472       10.4191481401
>   O        20.2466902057       31.0050977306       -1.3359780128
>   H        20.3299362589       30.2785268556       -1.9389296619
>   H        19.6777003080       31.6357105750       -1.5547295952
>   O        21.2957332204       33.1293109140      -25.0659621071
>   H        20.3592711216       33.4253012981      -25.4466125806
>   H        20.9447652999       32.6466105918      -24.3916283018
>   O         0.7089288469        0.9307218017       22.9887982360
>   H         1.5314847901        0.8490749712       22.5310575601
>   H         0.5441430575        1.8872689418       23.2516621019
>   O         7.3746399907       14.3127592248       16.5348425161
>   H         6.5466007130       14.4254548501       16.9898139753
>   H         7.6052849206       13.6548168638       17.2493931576
>   O        -6.2347290063       -1.5730966968       -9.5686602890
>   H        -5.4871593186       -1.6530761338       -8.8561541827
>   H        -6.7718035739       -2.3758355460       -9.4506081988
>   O         4.1237105737       27.8526125809      -17.5407129949
>   H         4.0923702511       26.9653003049      -17.9585134396
>   H         5.0631655714       28.1049626855      -17.7355819766
>   O         3.9048095294       10.9993650354       22.9499923672
>   H         4.0062720530       10.0140488786       23.1826699218
>   H         4.0861516253       11.3866144745       23.7864610303
>   O        19.0152979810       -5.9351715692        6.2028042600
>   H        18.4605234390       -6.4745692172        5.6818014424
>   H        19.2396476008       -6.4620406550        7.0197658840
>   O        11.0216358276       34.6048257097        2.7305894550
>   H        11.1156056781       34.8319742757        1.8093110583
>   H        10.3400079464       34.0000601295        2.5693445273
>   O       -10.5157839088       -7.9329341608       11.2106091514
>   H       -11.0911091981       -7.5398024873       10.5018246096
>   H       -10.3672907509       -8.7924109255       10.7746607022
>   O         4.4319386598       -1.5485855862       25.4116039540
>   H         3.8570621037       -1.1935351322       26.0861339612
>   H         5.0469005808       -0.8262948212       25.4201892039
>   O        28.5645454640       -4.9878471784       -8.5188991222
>   H        27.7186740182       -5.4723705471       -8.6074721317
>   H        28.7413452558       -5.1328247796       -7.6181314142
>   O        16.8076195127       10.3926352256       17.4717976356
>   H        16.2530097537        9.7296103637       18.0059385107
>   H        17.4412376654       10.6960518511       18.0799239677
>   O         5.6986236520       10.5704587253       -7.8979614715
>   H         5.8645730931       10.8767613035       -6.9360787362
>   H         5.8763439263        9.6219767116       -7.7972609625
>   O        -1.6407533652       22.4531576331        5.6999323132
>   H        -1.2083966517       23.3511084324        5.8486751133
>   H        -1.7580177109       22.0530093062        6.5574926186
>   O        24.2598161445      -19.7226302002      -16.0055656572
>   H        24.3640761910      -20.2051321253      -16.8160776202
>   H        23.4525468337      -20.1148735380      -15.7114773145
>   O         9.2705509590        5.2402601219       -1.4945948419
>   H         8.5640801519        4.5826338761       -1.3955554634
>   H         8.8326348516        6.0846007796       -1.5550973663
>   O         6.7394024871       17.2847757154        5.2451914312
>   H         6.7363545254       18.1918031920        5.5153954946
>   H         5.8131435731       17.0790377545        5.3952865725
>   O       -11.5260348557       -1.3910515053       33.6725762018
>   H       -11.0833545205       -0.9944057312       34.5242654623
>   H       -11.8815687893       -2.1376245948       34.2516036689
>   O        -1.2330960240       26.7412103644        0.1296496076
>   H        -0.3152599709       26.8434758121       -0.0739406639
>   H        -1.6953595955       26.4806945583       -0.6883021997
>   O         8.7319453941       -9.9465252126        1.1548249643
>   H         8.1761266121       -9.2009663887        1.4999148594
>   H         9.4588283911       -9.4157820738        0.7865321336
>   O        49.1697997010       22.2411405409      -10.9989465732
>   H        48.3460125030       22.5975059284      -11.4079883272
>   H        49.1394469315       21.2525900906      -10.8811842790
>   O       -32.2425222512      -11.3290845584       20.0288188258
>   H       -31.2915257379      -10.9759507595       19.9166953724
>   H       -32.7790952965      -10.9571378105       19.3141077428
>   O        17.3769639982      -10.4566394995      -12.2995408109
>   H        17.0648451297      -10.3530827607      -13.1979643339
>   H        17.1392239476       -9.6829211738      -11.7378212738
>   O         2.6135141953       33.1156286937       13.9345526957
>   H         3.3624134886       33.2391962148       14.5552438523
>   H         3.0213989872       33.1458067063       13.0930867071
>   O        14.5868377751       -2.6932021902       41.9781290382
>   H        14.0183707192       -1.9622717176       41.8173424621
>   H        13.9900845341       -3.3879238021       41.6910543874
>   O        21.5682597668       21.4293306110       11.8403196986
>   H        20.6823955164       21.5051771355       12.2788554732
>   H        21.4446865446       22.1422689608       11.1588448084
>   O        12.2991311296       10.6771343120        3.3375311410
>   H        13.1329813282       10.4565465159        3.7574072871
>   H        12.3953351295       10.2803575302        2.4686832579
>   O        22.2452045723       -5.8265081271        5.5871982404
>   H        21.3379297867       -6.0485326488        5.5357369261
>   H        22.5300973477       -6.3351844227        6.3453040119
>   O        16.9469554316        9.1243814143       11.8756849655
>   H        15.9526431659        9.0875886079       11.6429859630
>   H        17.0485195211        9.9875834892       12.1262729288
>   O         9.7177305035      -14.3859617906       27.8249890678
>   H        10.5597701723      -14.4154957715       27.4579044287
>   H         9.6831695556      -15.1552382005       28.4839326083
>   O       -13.6629108327       -4.4064514621       25.1733098360
>   H       -14.4945017496       -3.8741912777       25.0838650214
>   H       -13.5645567274       -4.8489294687       24.2748243500
>   O        -9.5725632503        2.8494928664        5.0341617995
>   H        -9.8240786064        3.6326650241        4.4811963649
>   H       -10.4268869379        2.5490604344        5.3934970589
>   O        30.9209730443       15.7884134053       25.4431217306
>   H        30.0732436836       15.4317938882       25.8198996058
>   H        30.9138257239       15.2320325770       24.6544943959
>   O        20.7186373918      -29.1517489603       -5.1848175387
>   H        20.7964057340      -28.8962777381       -4.1961956958
>   H        21.0306547989      -30.0389295043       -4.9674084411
>   O        28.1483028042        2.4421645637        0.1614008599
>   H        27.9271773579        2.8934717406        0.9710036546
>   H        27.6102281854        2.9438149002       -0.5073743121
>   O        19.2573687885      -26.4681252463        5.0466679158
>   H        18.4368324971      -26.1261185266        4.8355672553
>   H        19.0775425303      -27.3926151754        5.3973629690
>   O         5.0863788932       21.0777169993       24.3314638993
>   H         5.2558551253       21.8585269636       24.9170292706
>   H         4.1658859927       21.1561319289       24.6037099710
>   O        -9.9631443476       13.4016216675       14.4930730935
>   H       -10.6124219485       14.0611136748       14.7535667973
>   H        -9.2394049364       13.9589151957       13.9875674460
>   O        21.4850576900        9.3083240745        9.3080377410
>   H        21.3588305469        8.3963662823        8.9884720521
>   H        22.3492526429        9.5757056237        9.0756430545
>   O        11.7169508101       14.0684767368       22.3097978896
>   H        12.7015382313       13.9668778739       22.4072210705
>   H        11.5794463796       13.5486532966       21.4759857852
>   O       -39.8747286372        7.9144049409      -12.4730405107
>   H       -39.2204883948        8.1730444648      -11.7345840582
>   H       -39.3598200123        7.1970660440      -12.8927245625
>   O        28.1420851786       26.8894975529       -1.4821582577
>   H        28.3697519000       26.3264425437       -2.2012787625
>   H        27.4388820545       27.4701009434       -1.9620414935
>   O         5.6758154044       -2.0660881295      -12.0661764907
>   H         6.1352696534       -1.6650086364      -11.3198092630
>   H         5.0281327828       -1.2884553067      -12.3273453096
>   O        19.6844300889       15.5059126119        7.5128869969
>   H        19.7873260091       15.4137513544        6.5620955177
>   H        19.1156666084       16.2773164458        7.6245454335
>   O        12.5843221980       14.0239342588       -9.4777377365
>   H        13.3115615139       13.9548937120       -8.7818887849
>   H        12.3621501981       13.1113725912       -9.7424996330
>   O        28.4243673438       17.2676141431        4.7338459663
>   H        27.7504748671       17.2876360485        5.3693363679
>   H        28.0761065985       17.7945008662        3.9831593545
>   O         5.8742121177       14.8289039331       27.1099161454
>   H         5.3525824684       15.6592131853       27.1997053836
>   H         6.3065976417       15.1533492507       26.2850297064
>   O         8.5132167875      -10.5559447104        9.0104455180
>   H         8.2704214796       -9.6416914485        9.0119939760
>   H         8.0019786219      -10.7045800387        8.2403481006
>   O        -2.6083160392       15.6658631769       12.6584207732
>   H        -2.3887803942       15.0559933110       13.4106958795
>   H        -2.1417933909       16.4695507075       13.0638755274
>   O        -3.7869936202       30.1040185005        3.4711169518
>   H        -4.6481985268       29.7561844031        3.5419630263
>   H        -3.9660833918       30.5706402147        2.6657978969
> ```

Comment: Why regex tag? You are not using regex in the code.

Comment: I'm so unfamiliar with string/number formatting issues that I figured this sort of notation: %s/* would fall under the definition of regex.  If you could please let me know which tag you'd use instead, I would very much appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: `%s` is just string format placeholder. You are dealing with glob patterns here, not regex.

Comment: Thank you, Wictor--and I see you've changed the tag.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you're trying to use is written to be put and executed in the same directory where the files are.

In fact, `dir = os.getcwd()`, gets the current directory and the files are searched here.

You can put the script along with the files or replace dir line with:

```
dir = /YOUR/DIR/PATH
```